# MySQL: how to check if a string contains any character from a set?

Tags: mysql, sql, string

I have this set of invalid characters: `0-9!<>,;?=+()@#"°{}_$%/\^*`

I need to find out customers having a `firstname` or `lastname` containing any of them.

So far I'm using:

```
SELECT id_customer, firstname, lastname FROM customer WHERE (
    firstname REGEXP '[0-9]' OR lastname REGEXP '[0-9]' OR
    firstname LIKE '%.%' OR lastname LIKE '%.%' OR
    firstname LIKE '%@%' OR lastname LIKE '%@%'
)
```

Is there a cleaner approach to this without repeating `LIKE`?

Comment: `WHERE CONCAT(firstname, lastname) REGEXP '[0-9!<>,;?=+()@#"°{}_$%\/\\^*]'`

Answer (score 2):

This should do it:

```sql
WHERE firstname REGEXP '[0-9\\!\\<\\>,;\\?\\=\\+\\(\\)@\\#"\\{\\}_\\$%/\\\\\\^\\*]'
OR    lastname  REGEXP '[0-9\\!\\<\\>,;\\?\\=\\+\\(\\)@\\#"\\{\\}_\\$%/\\\\\\^\\*]'
```

But I would rather create a list of valid characters (they are finite and countable). This set could be inverted using `^`; the remaining logic remains the same:

```sql
-- names must only consist of a-z, hyphen, apostrophe and and dots
WHERE firstname REGEXP '[^a-z\\-''\\.]'
OR    lastname  REGEXP '[^a-z\\-''\\.]'
```